# Gnu Assembler (GAS) check if macro parameter is an immediate value or an undefined symbol

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

I expect I can check if macro parameter is undefined symbol or an immediately value:

I tried this one, I only can check if the parameter is a defined symbol or undefined symbol. But I don't have clue to check if parameter is an immediate value or an undefined symbol.

```
.macro mymacro myparam
 .ifdef "\myparam"
  .print "parameter is defined"
 .else
  .print "parameter is undefined or constan"
 .endif
.endm

mymacro FOO # will printing else block
mymacro 3 # same
```

Comment: I don't think GNU as macros support that.  Consider using different macros for the two cases.

Comment: I have tried it, I tried to do arithmatic operation. If it's operable then it must be immediate value, otherwise it's an undefined symbol. Unfortunately when the parameter is undefined symbol it throws error. I expect there are try-catch block atleast.

Comment: Macro expansion happens before syntactical analysis, so what you envision is not really possible.  Likely for the same reason, symbols cannot be distinguished from constants.

Comment: You expect there to be a try/catch mechanism in the GAS macro language??  Prepare to be disappointed; it's not like modern C++ templates where you can deduce things about types with SFINAE.